# How to wrap my listview so it doesn't end abruptly at device height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've been trying to wrap my head around how I can solve the problem that my listview ends abruptly. I know it's caused by the container inside the stack that uses the .height. But I cant figure out how I can wrap the second container (with the white color) to be as long as the listview. The first container is to give edges to the background. I've tried wrapping it in columns and expanded but I might not fully understand those concepts yet, and how they interact. See images.

Any help or explanation on how to wrap this better would be great!

Github Link: https://github.com/Elqauto/stack/

[image]

[image]

```
Widget _detailBody(
      BuildContext context, Episodes episode, String herotag) {
    return ListView(children: [
      Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Color.fromARGB(207, 128, 82, 255)),
          Positioned(
              top: 75.0,
              child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(45.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(45.0),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.white),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)),
          Positioned(
              top: 30.0,
              child: Hero(
                  tag: herotag,
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  herotag.substring(0, herotag.length - 2)),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      height: 150.0,
                      width: 150.0))),
          Positioned(
              top: 185.0,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Center(child: Text("Episodes: " + episode.count.toString()))
                ],
              )),
          Positioned(
            top: 210,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: episode.items.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return _detailListViewItem(episode.items[index], context);
                  }),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a higher chance of having your question answered if you post an example project that can replicate your issue on GitHub and share the code here so we can help you better.

Comment: Doing as @VandadNahavandipoor said would a great help. If I'm getting your question right, why don't you assign white color to the ```Container ``` which wraps ```ListVew```?

Comment: Thanks @VandadNahavandipoor and Xoltawn, added the github link for the project. I could indeed make that white, but it still inherits the height of the top container, any ideas there?